# Windows won't boot after power cut. Windows installation USB won't boot either

Tags: windows, boot, usb, ssd, bios

A few months ago, a very brief power outage occurred while I was using Windows 10. It lasted less than a second and when I turned my computer on again, it booted into Ubuntu, which was installed on an old HDD that I rarely used, instead of my Windows SSD, which used to be the default boot option. I tried to manually boot into that SSD, but it was not listed as an option.

Browsing the contents of the SSD through Ubuntu is possible and all the files seem to be there. Gnome disks reports a bad sector, though I'm not sure if that happened before or after the power cut.

I thought that maybe the UEFI entry for Windows got somehow deleted and I tried to boot into a Windows installation USB, as well as a Windows recovery drive, to see if I can restore it from the command line, but they won't boot either. I toggled CSM support and secure boot on and off, I used different flash drives, I tried creating them with Rufus, Windows Installation Media Tool and also manually and tried both GPT and MBR options, but they never get past showing the Windows logo and/or loading animation, or a black screen, even after waiting for a long time. The flash drives boot normally on other other computers. Updating BIOS also didn't help and booting from a CD is not an option.

Linux live systems boot normally from USBs and Windows Installation USBs used to work in the past, too, as that's what I used to install Windows on the SSD.

Changing the SATA mode from AHCI to RAID made the Windows USBs boot, but my SSD was inaccessible. (And caused Ubuntu not to boot.)

I haven't tried transplanting the SSD to another computer to see if it boots, but I was wondering if I can find a solution to my problem before I do that. Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility: as an SSD dies, it goes into read-only mode. That may leave it accessible,  but not bootable.

Comment: Was Windows installed in Legacy Mode? The only reason you would enable CSM is if that’s the case. It makes no sense to enable RAID mode if Windows was installed with it enabled. For your own sanity stop disabling and enabling options, that were not disabled or enabled, because by doing so you only lessen the chances we can help you. Your suspicions that this an EFI are spot on, but CSM is incompatible with UEFI Windows installations, and enabling RAID mode wouldn’t solve an EFI partition problem.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Maybe. But it's a relatively new SSD. Also, this doesn't explain why the USBs don't boot.

Comment: @Ramhound Unless I remember wrong, it wasn't installed in legacy mode. I tried these different settings to get the USBs to work. I don't know why they only boot when RAID mode is selected.